# Not displaying AF selection modes on LCD

Tags: equipment-recommendation, autofocus, canon-5d

In my Canon 5D Mark IV, AF selection modes are not displaying on LCD, even after pressing the AF points button, which is placed at the corner of the camera.

Comment: Are you talking about the LCD on the back of the camera? Or the overlay LCD that shows in the viewfinder? Are you trying to change the AF Selection Mode? Or are you trying to change the selected AF points from within the current AF Selection Mode? If the latter, what AF Selection Mode are you in?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried it on my 700D.

in the options there are "AF options" to be selected.

- Fast: You can see the AF points. Whenever you focus, the mirror goes down to accomodete the focus. then the mirror is released to either show the preview or th capture te image.
- FlexiZone - Multi: You cannot see the AF points, the AF uses the senor data to focus multiple objects (emphasized by green rectangles.)
- FlexiZone - Single: You cannot see the AF points. Instead of them there is a white rectangle to emphasize the area where the AF will be estimated. I can change it using the touchscreen.

I think you have FlexiZone selected. This option is in menu under "lifeview" bookmark (4th in case of 700D).

Comment: "AF points" and "AF Selection Modes" are two different things.